# Check whether a default-deleted function template is explicitly specialized for a specific type?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, template-instantiation, delete-keyword

(This question has been significantly edited, sorry.)

Suppose I have several non-constexpr function templates, which default to being deleted:

```
template <typename T> void foo() = delete;
template <typename T> int  bar(int x) = delete;
// etc.
```

and have some explicit specialization as an exception to the general-case deletion.

I want to write code (e.g. a trait class?) which, given the identifier of one of these functions and a type T, detects, at compile-time, whether the specified function is explicitly specialized for type T. The code needs to be generic, i.e. not a separate detector for each of the functions.

Notes:

- Looking for a C++11 solution.
- We may assume the specified function is deleted by default - if that helps.
- Ideally, it would like like `instantiation_exists<decltype(foo), foo, int>::value` or `instantiation_exists<int>(foo, tag<int>)` or `instantiation_exists(foo, tag<int>)` or something along those lines.

---

**Edit:** @Jarod42's wrote up an [SFINAE example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c538c4d4e3912c39) in a comment on an earlier version of this question, which was about a per-single-function detector. I tried to generalize/genericize it using a template-template parameter:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> void foo() = delete;
template <> void foo<int>() {}

template <template<typename U> typename F, typename T, typename = decltype(F<T>()) >
std::true_type test(int);

template  <template<typename U> typename F, typename T>
std::false_type test(...);

template <typename T>
using foo_is_defined = decltype(test<foo<T>, T>(0));

static_assert(foo_is_defined<int>::value);
static_assert(not foo_is_defined<int*>::value);
```

but that was [a wash](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8aa3298ac61ed317) (Coliru).

Comment: SFINAE of `foo<MyType>()`? [Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c538c4d4e3912c39)

Comment: @Jarod42: Sorry, edited to make the question harder, see edit.

Comment: @walnut: Yes, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot pass template function, or overloads in template parameter.

We can turn those function in functor:

```
template <typename T>
struct identity_type
{
    using type = T;  
};

template <typename F, typename T, typename = decltype(std::declval<F>()(identity_type<T>{})) >
std::true_type test(int);

template  <typename F, typename T>
std::false_type test(...);

auto foos = [](auto tag, auto&&... args)
-> decltype(foo<typename decltype(tag)::type>((decltype(args))(args)...))
{
    return foo<typename decltype(tag)::type>((decltype(args))(args)...);
};

template <typename T>
using is_foo = decltype(test<decltype(foos), T>(0));
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ed8d3451b997cdd)

I use generic lambda, so C++14.

in C++11, it would be really verbose:

```
struct foos
{
    template <typename T, typename... Ts>
    auto operator()(identity_type<T>, Ts&&... args) const
    -> decltype(foo<T>(std::forward<Ts>(args)...))
    {
        return foo<T>(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    };
};
```

Comment: But this means I need to create a lambda or a struct for each single function I want to test for, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's my proposal. MACRO can be a solution to pass name (and so overload/template function) to limit verbosity.

Comment: I was afraid you were going to say something like that :-(